# Mako Top Level Lookup Exception

Tags: python, html, css, mako

I have to include css in my mako template. I tried this sample code but I am getting this error, I dont know why?

> line 262, in get_template raise exceptions.TopLevelLookupException(
> mako.exceptions.TopLevelLookupException: Cant locate template for uri
> 'table_design'

```
lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['.', '/Programs/Python/Python39/templates'])

try:
    template = lookup.get_template('table_design.css')
    print(template.render())
except:
    print(exceptions.text_error_template().render())
```

Comment: Surely the exception text is self-explanatory

Comment: I got that explanation. But I tried keeping it everywhere in the template folder, outside it also. even on my desktop folder. No luck